# Unneccessary Privacy Policy For Entitlements?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, submit, storekit

I am attempting to submit my first app into the ios app store, however I am receiving this annoying error:

```
Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments]
must have a privacy policy URL for [English]. 
If your app doesn’t use these entitlements,
remove them from your app and upload a new  binary.
```

I am implementing in app purchases and have successfully tested them.
I don't know why I am getting this error?
I have added the StoreKit framework.
In my Capabilities section in Xcode I have in-app purchases turned on with no warnings or errors.

Can anyone explain or help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the App Store, and is [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also faced the same problem, which finally I resolved and uploaded.
You enabled in-app purchases in your APPId, that's why you got this error. So you must enter a privacy policy URL (but it is displayed as optional) in iTunes Connect.
[image: iTunes Connect Privacy Policy URL Entry]

Comment: I was getting this error when submitting for External Testing. I had to add the Privacy Policy URL under `Activity -> All Builds -> iOS Builds -> (Specific Build)`. Adding the URL on the App Store section only didn't help.

Comment: There is nowhere to specify the Privacy Policy URL under that path (June 2017).

Answer (score -3):

Using in app purchases requires you to keep track for the devices that made those purchases so that if that information is lost, then the device can use your method of checking if that content should belong on the device or not, then place it there. Mainly to make sure that user data and device data are both safe. Refer to the reference for more info.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At the bottom of the reference, it mentions that privacy policies are only required for subscriptions which my app does not include?

Comment: Even so, it says for all usage of device data. Here is another reference stating that it's mainly for the purpose of telling your users how you plan to use the data you collect. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW6

Comment: so you're saying, every single app that has any type of in app purchase has a privacy policy for it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a legal process. When users make purchases through their iTunes account and authenticate through your app, they'll want to make sure you're not logging that info. It's reasons like that a privacy policy is created.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe that. I am just an indie dev, where can I find info on privacy policy creating for simple in app purchase for a game?

Comment: Think of it like a resume. It can't write it for you, but there are templates and tools to help you come up with one. I don't suggest using the generator, because this link is a blog, but this should point you in the right direction to start one. http://www.iubenda.com/blog/2013/06/14/privacy-policy-for-ios-apps/

Comment: I'm guessing I have to purchase a domain too in order to host my privacy policy?

Comment: Buy one or get a free subdomain from a trusty website.

Comment: This is entirely untrue. You don't need a privacy policy for non-subscription in-app purchases.