# External tester submission error (Beta App Review). Entitlements for Apple Pay

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, applepay

I am getting an error while submitting an app for External tester in App store. In the application, I have used Apple Pay feature.
While submitting app for External tester in Testflight at that time I am getting error

> Apps that use the entitlements [com.apple.developer.in-app-payments] must have a privacy policy for [UK English]. If your app doesn’t use these entitlements, remove them from your app and upload a new binary.

[image]

[image]

I have already added privacy policy link in App store.
[Unneccessary Privacy Policy For Entitlements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582502/unneccessary-privacy-policy-for-entitlements)

Comment: There is a specific privacy policy url field under "Test Information".  Have you entered a privacy policy url for UK english there?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much you save me day!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific privacy policy URL field under "Test Information" that is required for TestFlight testing.  Make sure you have entered your privacy policy URL there for UK English.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apple Pay or any in-App Purchase in your app and want to upload on testflight you must be given it's privacy policy..

**I had to add the Privacy Policy URL under TestFlight -> Test Information -> Privacy Policy URL and add any specific your privacy URL..**

[image]

and then you can add all tester again with your specific build now you can see your error is gone.. Enjoy.